Color where the user touches the screen - kotlin android
I have this function that allows the user to paint on the screen. It works correctly in the emulator; where I touch, the screen is painted. However, when I tested it on my tablet, it is very offset. If I click in the middle of the screen, it paints in the bottom right corner. Does anyone know how to fix this offset?
private fun handleTouch(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    val drawable = drawable ?: return false

    val imageWidth = drawable.intrinsicWidth
    val imageHeight = drawable.intrinsicHeight
    val viewWidth = width
    val viewHeight = height

    val scaleX = viewWidth.toFloat() / imageWidth
    val scaleY = viewHeight.toFloat() / imageHeight
    val scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY)

    val correctedX = ((event.x - (viewWidth - imageWidth * scale) / 2) / scale).toInt()
    val correctedY = ((event.y - (viewHeight - imageHeight * scale) / 2) / scale).toInt()

    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            drawOnImage(correctedX, correctedY)
            return true
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            performClick()
            return true
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            drawOnImage(correctedX, correctedY)
            drawingListener?.onDrawing() 
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

fun drawOnImage(x: Int, y: Int) {
        val canvas = Canvas((drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap)
        canvas.drawCircle(x.toFloat(), y.toFloat(), paint.strokeWidth / 2, paint)
        invalidate()
    }

xml
<com.my.app.CustomImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="paint" />

